# TypeScript thinks mongoose lean returns an array

Tags: typescript, generics, mongoose

I'm trying to make a generic crud controller with typescript / mongoose, and ran into a type issue, if I do the following, it works fine:

```
async findOne<T>(id: number): Promise<T> {
    return this._collection.findOne({ _id: id }, null, { lean: true });
}
```

But using .lean() gives a type error, even though the result is the same (as far as I can see anyways):

```
async findOne<T>(id: number): Promise<T> {
    return this._collection.findOne({ _id: id }).lean();
}
```

It thinks that .lean() can return T or T[].

In case this is normal for findOne() somehow, I also have the same issue with findById, which I thought could only ever return one object:

```
async findById<T>(id: number): Promise<T> {
    return this._collection.findById(id).lean(); // error
    // return this._collection.findById(id, null, {lean: true}); <-- works
}
```

What is the difference / problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly determine retuned value of `lean` function

```js
async findOne<T>(id: number): Promise<T> {
    return this._collection.findOne({ _id: id }).lean<T>();
}
```